# Android Collapsing Toolbar not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-scrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am following this example "http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/". I want an image that moves up with the parallax effect.But when I run my app nothing shows up. I get a blank white screen.Any help?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HELLO"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);


    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity android:name=".Vendor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.vendor" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>





        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Style:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Did you call setContentView?

Comment: @EugenPechanec- yes, I did

Comment: show your java code, as xml seems to be fine.

Comment: @UMESH0492- My java code is just an Activty where I set the Content view in the Oncreate method

Comment: @amanda45 Show it anyway, also post build.gradle so we know what support libs version you use and post your styles.xml so we know how your theme is defined. Oh and AndroidManifest.xml. Please write a file name above each of these, we can guess if it's a XML or Java.

Comment: I'm not sure `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is a good idea on the toolbar

Comment: @EugenPechanec-I posted the files